# os.path.abspath doesn't give the full path of the working direcory

Tags: python, shutil, python-os

I want to create a file finder in Python to get some images of a big folder tree, that is not sorted. Now I have the problem that, if I want to copy my found files into another folder an Error appears. The reason for that is, that the path of the file is incomplete.

I have already tried the relative and absolute path of the file.
I also tried it with removing the '\' in the path with os.path.normpath(), but even that did not work for me. But technically that should not matter anyway.

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\python project\fileFinder\Media"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".jpg"):
            shutil.copyfile(os.path.abspath(file)), r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\python project\fileFinder\found")
```

In 'Media' are all the different folders with many subfolders.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/python project/fileFinder/Finder.py", line 6, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(file)), r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\python project\fileFinder\found")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\python project\\fileFinder\\0193e055-d3e7-4992-869b-e0734e9fb2e7.jpg'
```

Comment: Use `os.path.join(root, file)` instead.  `os.path.abspath(...)` will just give you a filename relative to your current directory as you found.  You want the full path relative to `root` in this case, which is the directory currently being walked.

Comment: Okay, I have changed it, but it still gives me an error probably because I did something wrong. ```python
shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\python project\fileFinder\Media", file), r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\python project\fileFinder\found")
```

Comment: No, I mean literally write exactly what I just did: `os.path.join(root, file)`.  See also the examples in the docs for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Is this what you did: **shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(root, file), r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\python project\fileFinder\found")**